# Make QGraphicsItem movable by right mouse button instead of left

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

Is it possible to create a movable QGraphicsItem that is moved with the right mouse button instead of the left one?

The only thing I could find by searching was a thread [which suggests using QGraphicsItem::setAcceptedMouseButtons()](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/17546-ItemIsMovable), and I tried setting it to accept only right clicks, but then the items stopped being movable at all.

This is the code I tried:

```
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
QGraphicsRectItem *item = scene->addRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
item->setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::RightButton);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that the code in `QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent` is hard wired to move only on the left button -- regardless of the parameters passed to `setAcceptedMouseButtons`.  So if you want to move on the right button I think you'll have to override `mouseMoveEvent` and do the leg work yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected as well, though I wasn't sure. I might try filtering the events and replacing the mouse button to fool the object it's a left click, while filtering out real left clicks.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the source code eventually, and as @G.M. pointed out, the code of QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent() explicitly checks for left mouse button:

```
void QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if ((event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) && (flags() & ItemIsMovable)) {
```

So nothing can be done except reimplement the moving in a derived class.